# Creating an interactive website design

Tags: html

What is the best and easy tool to create an interactive rubric like this:

http://www.achievementfirst.org/high-school/interactive-writing-rubric/#position

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. That being said [this](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navs/#tabs) could help you.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to make menus, submenus and tabs with twitter's [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) framework in [dreameweaver](http://adobe.com/fr/products/dreamweaver.html). to have effect exactly like this you have to add your custom css styling.